# On OSX, how are zip archives made through Terminal excluding specific files?

Tags: macos, terminal, zip, archiving

On Mac, a lot of excess files are added in a zip archive that can be undesirable on other platforms, mainly .DS_Store files and the main _MACOSX folder. The OSX platform has a zip utility built in, but I'm not sure on how to use it to make archives that exclude specified files. How is this done?

Comment: There may be manual page documentation for it. Try `man zip` in a Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip` has a `-x` options that allows you to exclude some files.

For example :

`zip -r my.zip . -x "*.DS_Store"` compress you current directory and excludes your .DS_Store files. You can use `-x` multiple times if you want the exclude other patterns !

Comment: Awesome! Can you use it repeatedly, like `zip -r my.zip . -x "*.DS_Store" -x "_MACOSX"`? Also, is the command executed inside of an overhead directory or inside the directory desired for compression?

Comment: The target destination of your zip if the first parameter. `my.zip` could have been `~/Desktop/my.zip` !